# Nifi PutMongo - How to insert document into MongoDB using attribute values of Flow File but not Flow File content?

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I am trying to insert a document into mongodb using apache NiFi. I want to insert a document just from Flow File attributes but not the Flow File content.

I have tried using PutMongo processor but it insert the content of the Flow file which I don't want it to insert. I need to insert a custom document by using the flow file's attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a processor like AttributesToJson, or ReplaceText, to overwrite the flow file content with the attributes that you want to use for the Mongo document.

Comment: I dont want change the flow file's content.

Comment: Ok well there is no processor that inserts a mongo document from attributes, you could fork the flow where you send the flow down one path with the original content and then another path that replaces the content with the attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jolt JSON for customizing or limit your attribute.

https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception